# The number of derivatives returned by func() must equal the length of the initial conditions vector

Tags: dsolve

while related questions and replies exist, I could not translate them to my own problem, so here it goes:

```
ratedegrad<-0.012   
releaser<-0.0016666667
times2<-seq(from=1, to=240, by=1)
state2<-c(degrad=300,titre=101,released=13.7)

dtitre2<-function(y,t,parms) {
with(as.list(y), {   
dX2=-ratedegrad*titre                           
dY2=(-releaser*titre)-(ratedegrad*titre)                                        
dZ2= releaser*titre                                 

list(c(abs(dX2),dY2,dZ2)) } )
}  
outtitre2<-ode(y=state2,times=times2,func=dtitre2,parms=NULL)
plot(outtitre2)
```

the error message I get is :
The number of derivatives returned by func() (153) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (3)

thank you!